# How can I get the username from a failed login using spring security?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security

We're using spring security 3.0.5, Java 1.6 and Tomcat 6.0.32.  In our .xml config file we've got:

```
<form-login login-page="/index.html" default-target-url="/postSignin.html" always-use-default-target="true"
 authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>
```

and our `authenticationFailureHandler` defined as:

```
<beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
   <beans:property name="exceptionMappings">
      <beans:props>
    <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException">/index.html?authenticationFailure=true</beans:prop>
    </beans:props>
   </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

**Java**

```
    @RequestMapping(params={"authenticationFailure=true"}, value ="/index.html")
    public String handleInvalidLogin(HttpServletRequest request) {
       //...  How can I get the username that was used???
       // I've tried:
       Object username = request.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY");
       Object username = request.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME");  // deprecated
    }
```

So we're directing all `BadCredentialsExceptions` to the `index.html` and `IndexController`.  In the `IndexController` I'd like to get the `username` that was used for the failed login attempt.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Okay so the answer turned out to be something extremely simple yet as far as I can tell, not greatly discussed or documented.

Here's all I had to do (no configurations anywhere just created this class)...

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent> {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyApplicationListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event) {
        Object userName = event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        Object credentials = event.getAuthentication().getCredentials();
        LOG.debug("Failed login using USERNAME [" + userName + "]");
        LOG.debug("Failed login using PASSWORD [" + credentials + "]");
    }
}
```

I'm far from a spring security expert so if anyone reads this and knows of a reason we shouldn't do it like this or knows a better way I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: We have this exact code working in our set up.  I can't tell you why it wouldn't work in yours.  We didn't have to configure anything new nor change any .xml file anywhere.  The annotations seem to point spring at this code and execute it when there is a bad login.  It works perfectly for us.

Comment: maybe it does require some other configuration. By the way, I have found an alternative solution. Thank you for the information, though :)

Comment: Hi Kasdega,
How can I use the above solution to access the username in the controller? I want the username in a controller.

Comment: @LittleLebowski I believe Hoang Long answered your question with his answer to my question.  String  username = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME");

Comment: @kasdega Hello m trying the same for the 3 login attemps, but its not working. So can post your code or help me any way out

Comment: @kasdega here you have a create a bean for your 'MyApplicationListner' class in 'ApplicationContext.xml' or any other configuration file, which is visible to project application context.

Answer (score 22):

I did it this way:

1. Created a class that extends `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`
2. Overrid the `onAuthenticationFailure` method, which receives an `HttpServletRequest` as a parameter.
3. `request.getParameter("username")`, where `"username"` is the name of my input in my HTML form.

Comment: It works fine, just a comment, if you are using the default name in the form for the input text which is **j_username** then you must Catch it like this. `request.getParameter("j_username")`.

Answer (score 5):

You could instead supply your own version of [DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher.html) and override the publishAuthenticationFailure method.

Comment: You would need to wire in your owner implementation.  See if you can extend DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher.  Then wire that in to the ProviderManager (which is an implementation of AuthenticationManager, which you need to have declared in Spring Security).  That class has a method setAuthenticationEventPublisher.

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be much information on this solution, but if you set [failureForwardUrl](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/FormLoginConfigurer.html#failureForwardUrl-java.lang.String-) in your Spring Security configuration, you will be forwarded to the error page instead of redirected. You can then easily retrieve the username and password.
For example, in your config add:
`.and().formLogin().failureForwardUrl("/login/failed")` (* url must be different from the login page url)

And in your login controller, the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/failed")
public String loginfailed(@ModelAttribute(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY) String user, @ModelAttribute(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY) String password) {
     // Your code here
}
```

SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY, SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY are the default names, but you can set these in the FormLoginConfigurer as well:

```
.and().formLogin().usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password").failureForwardUrl("/login/failed")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found this works for me. Unfortunately, I still not found the exact location of this in SpringSecurity documents:

In any action, you can check the last-used username (no matter what the login was failed or not):

```
    String  username = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME");
```

Comment: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY is the constant that corresponds to the attribute name. It is now deprecated.

Comment: @mrbaboo: so it's why I can't find anything about this constant. So it's deprecated, do you know any alternative way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the code that stored this deprecated value in the session was removed in the 3.1.0 release of Spring Security.  You'll have to use one of the other methods described above if you want to achieve this effect with recent versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Spring AOP, you can add the below code to your Aspect class:

```
private String usernameParameter = "username"; 

@Before("execution(* org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(..))")
public void beforeLoginFailure(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) joinPoint.getArgs()[0];
        AuthenticationException exceptionObj = (AuthenticationException) joinPoint.getArgs()[2];

        String username = request.getParameter(usernameParameter);

        System.out.println(">>> Aspect check: AuthenticationException:  "+exceptionObj.getMessage());
        System.out.println(">>> Aspect check: user: "+ username + " failed to log in.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old thread, but if you are using a relatively current "spring-boot-starter-security" package, here's how I did it:

I set my AuthenticationFailureHandler like so:

```
SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler("/my-error-url");
handler.setUseForward(true);
```

This will set the last exception into the request:

```
//from SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler source
request.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION", exception);
```

Then from my controller I can get the bad username:

```
RequestMapping("/impersonate-error")
public String impersonateErrorPage(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    AuthenticationException ex = (AuthenticationException)request.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION");
    if(ex != null) {
        logger.debug("Impersonate message: " + ex.getMessage());
        model.put("badName", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return "impersonate-error";
}
```