# Spring. populate j_username after failed login

Tags: spring-security

I'm implementing authentication functionality in my application. When credentials are invalid I'd like to move on the same login page but with populated j_username textfield. But I see no way to do this.

my login.jsp:

```
<html>
<head> <!-- connecting javascripts and styles --> </head>
<body>
<c:set var="base" value="/myProject" /> 

    <form:form commandName="loginUser" method="POST" action="${base}/j_spring_security_check">
        <h3 align="center"><spring:message code="login.header" /></h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><spring:message code="login.label.login" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="j_username" /></td>
                <td><div id="j_username" class="errors"><span id="j_username_stub"/><form:errors path="login" /></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><spring:message code="login.label.password" /></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="j_password" /></td>
                <td><div id="j_password" class="errors"><span id="j_password_stub"/></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><spring:message code="login.label.rememberme" /></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="login.button.login" />" /></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</html>
```

my spring-security.xml:

```
 <security:http pattern="/static/**" security="none" />

    <security:http use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <security:http-basic />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/jsp/login*" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/jsp/admin/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:form-login
                login-page="/"
                default-target-url="/jsp/admin/admin.jsp"
                authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed"/>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="true" logout-success-url="/" />
        <security:anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
        <security:remember-me key="sparkBitAuthToken" token-validity-seconds="864000" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/> <!-- bCrypt encoder -->

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.myproject.web.authentication.SparkBitUserDetailsService" />
```

my loginController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping
    public String getLoginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/loginFailed")
    public String getLoginPageOnError(Model model, @ModelAttribute("loginUser") LoginUserBean entity, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {
        result.rejectValue("login", "error.login.credentials", "Invalid credentials ...");
        return "login";
    }
    }
```

in my controller I have no data for filled form

Also I'm getting in stuck as on invalid credentials page refreshs without loading javascript. What can be wrong?

Thanks in advice

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13035995/1700321.

Comment: and how can I get userPrincipal from // public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException  ? As I now know I shouldn't use AuthenticationException for this as all methods about getting user data are deprecated

Comment: IMHO, here is a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676206/how-can-i-get-the-username-from-a-failed-login-using-spring-security