# get userid on Controller classes when hit ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've already setup my spring security, something like below. I would like to get the user id in those controller classes so that I can update the fail count if there is a bad credential or i would like to redirect it to a reset password page is password already expired.

Thanks in advance.

```
<beans:bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="exceptionMappings">
        <beans:props>           
            <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException">/login_error</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException">/password_expired</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException">/locked</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="org.springframework.secuirty.authentication.DisabledException">/disabled</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<http use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-handler-ref="exceptionTranslationFilter" />
</http>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also an ApplicationListener that can be added to listen to BadCredentials events, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676206/how-can-i-get-the-username-from-a-failed-login-using-spring-security)

**Edited:**
How about adding AuthenticationSuccessHandler also, saw this example: [Redirect to different pages after Login with Spring Security](http://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login)

Comment: Yea I've saw that. It works great with `BadCredentialsException` and `LockedException`. but it when it hit `CredentialsExpiredException`. I want it to redirect to a change password page, which cant be done in `ApplicationListener`

Comment: How about adding AuthenticationSuccessHandler then? link added to edited response

Comment: But that would be not right.. Because the use is authenticated.. And the user will be able to go to other page thru URL...

Comment: Just one more note, it seems that if AuthenticationSuccessHandler is  implemented, it is possible to set "authentication.setAuthenticated(false);" within onAuthenticationSuccess method, prior to redirecting to the changePassword page.   This seems to be able to prevent user from accessing other Authenticated pages.  It also assumes that the changePassword page should not require the user to be already authenticated.   This does seem to work for me, but have not seen any other post confirming this approach.  And defer to other responders to  suggest best practice/approaches.

Comment: Thanks.. i think if no other responders, i guess this will be the best workaround that I can think of.